# How do I make functions run as subprocesses in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want my Python script to be able to run one of its functions as subprocesses. How should I do that?

Here is a mock-up script of my intention:

```
#!/urs/bin/env python

def print_mynumber(foo):
    """This function is obviously more complicated in my script.
    It should be run as a subprocess."""
    print(foo)

for foo in [1,2,3]:
    print_mynumber(foo) # Each call of this function should span a new process.
    # subprocess(print_mynumber(foo))
```

Thank you for your suggestions. It is a little hard for me to formulate the problem correctly, and thus to make the appropriate web search.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def print_mynumber(foo):
    """This function is obviously more complicated in my script.
    It should be run as a subprocess."""
    print(foo)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for foo in [1,2,3]:
        proc = mp.Process(target = print_mynumber, args = (foo, ))
        proc.start()
```

---

You might not want to be creating one process for each call to `print_mynumber`, especially if the list `foo` iterates over is long. A better way in that case would be to use a multiprocessing pool:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def print_mynumber(foo):
    """This function is obviously more complicated in my script.
    It should be run as a subprocess."""
    print(foo)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool()
    pool.map(print_mynumber, [1,2,3])
```

The pool, be default, will create N worker processes, where `N` is the number of cpus (or cores) the machine possesses. `pool.map` behaves much like the Python builtin `map` command, except that it farms out tasks to the pool of workers.